# How do i mock this line of code on kotlin/android

Tags: android, junit4, kotlin-android-extensions

How do i mock this. I'm using kotlin on android.

```
eventBus.asObservable().subscribe(::onNewEvent)
```

So far i have

```
whenever(eventBus.asObservable()).doReturn(mock<Observable<Event>>())
```

Comment: Do you want to test the behavior of the subscription and that `::onNewEvent` behaves correctly? It would be good to have more information about your actual goal.

Comment: Yes i want to test the subscription and that ::onEvent behaves correctly. Right now i'm getting NPR on eventBus.asObservable().subscribe(::onNewEvent), because of obvious reasons.

Comment: If you have a NPE, you should post the stack trace. Also a bit more context would be helpful. Is eventBus a dependency injected into the the object? Is it mocked or spyed on in the test?